# function overriding, onload precedence

Tags: javascript

I'm developing some library and created this buggy code:

```
//-------------------
Gmaps = {};
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle(); //there exists a default callback function in the created object
function load_map() {
  Gmaps.map.callback();
};
window.onload = load_map();
//--------------------
Gmaps.map.callback = function(){ alert('ok'); }
```

I thought, because the whole page is loaded, that `callback` would have been changed and `alert` message displayed.

But it's not the case and I haven't any error message in firebug.

If I then execute `Gmaps.map.callback()` in console, it works fine.

Is there any reason why the `callback` isn't overriden?

For context sake, code between `---------` is created by the library but developers would be able to override some functions in his html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not executing `load_map` onload. You're executing it immediately here:

```
window.onload = load_map();
```

and storing it's return value inside `window.onload`, so nothing is happening onload. Just change that line to:

```
window.onload = load_map;
```